# How to perform Load Test of WCF service having WebHttpBinding with JMeter

Tags: wcf, testing, jmeter, webhttpbinding

I am very new for JMeter. I want to test my WCF service which is using WebHttpBinding. I have gone through the documentation but no help in my case. Can you please suggest how to do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Most likely you need to add at least [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json`.
2. You can use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to inspect request and response details - this way you'll be able to get more troubleshooting information.
3. Be aware of [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor) and [JSON Path Assertion](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion) which are extremely handy when it comes to working with JSON data.

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more details on web services load testing with JMeter.